# Get fft from a sequence and use sliding windows on it

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence:

```
n=1:500

X=sqrt(10)*exp(0.1i*pi*n) + sqrt(10)*exp(0.12i*pi*n)+rand(1,n);
```

and I want to get fft from X1 until X16 then X2 until X17 then X3 until X18 ...  and then plot it with a sliding windows? Is there another solution for this in Matlab?

Comment: **Another** solution?  What's the existing solution?

Answer (score 0):

**fft** is a Matlab function that will return the discrete fft of a series of data. You can iterate through your data and call fft on each window.